# computing pi value using python, division always zero

Tags: python, math

I am trying to use python to compute an approximation of (pi) using unlimited series.

stopping condition is for `accuracy = 10**(-9)`

accuracy is `abs(exact_pi-computed_pi)`

my code:

```py
from math import sqrt

exact_pi=3.14159265358979323846
accuracy=10**(-9)
computed_pi=float(sqrt(12))
k=1

while abs(float(computed_pi)-float(exact_pi))>accuracy:
   
    num1=float((-3)**(-k))
    num2=float((2*k+1))
    computed_pi=float(computed_pi)+ float(num1/num2)
    k=k+1
```

The result of  `float(num1/num2)` after some iterations for `k=100` for example it `outputs 0` so it gets into an infinite loop. can someone help?

[PI FORMULA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA4pJ.png)

Comment: Is `accuracy = 10**(-9)` even possible with python's `float`?

Comment: The formula you are using seems to be a summation. I don't see any summations going on in your code.

Comment: This seems like a typo where you are using `*` instead of `+`

Comment: thx i'll dit the code regarding the ```+``` but still the problem is in the division part it gives ```0``` @JohnColeman  
@quamrana

Comment: @JohnColeman: I think it's worse than that. There needs to be a separate term for summation and another for the final multiply by root 12

Comment: You should probably use some maths instead of brute force.

Comment: @quamrana You are right. I noticed that when I sat down to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@quamrana** noticed you have missed sum operation.

```py
# your code before while

while abs(computed_pi - exact_pi) > accuracy:
    multiplier = sum((-3)**(-i)/(2 * i + 1) for i in range(k))
    computed_pi = 12**0.5 * multiplier
    k += 1
```

or slightly optimized version (thanks again to quamrana)

```py
multipler = 0
while abs(computed_pi - exact_pi) > accuracy:
    multiplier += (-3)**(-k) / (2 * k + 1)
    computed_pi = 12**0.5 * multiplier
    k += 1
```

Comment: i guess it's correct because he is summing for i going from 0 to k and if the condition didn't match he increments K and do the sum all over till it finds the K needed.  i guess. i someone has another opinion please mention it . but i think @Ivan Trushin has a point

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things wrong with your code:

1. You are initializing `computed_pi` to be `sqrt(12)` rather than `0`
2. You are starting your sum at `k=1` rather than `k=0`
3. You aren't accumulating the terms
4. You are wasting cpu cycles (and sacrificing readability) constant;y converting floats to floats.

Fixing these leads to:

```
from math import sqrt

exact_pi=3.14159265358979323846
accuracy=10**(-9)
computed_pi=0
factor = sqrt(12)
k=0

while abs(computed_pi - exact_pi)>accuracy:
   
    num1=(-3)**(-k)
    num2=2*k+1
    computed_pi = computed_pi + factor * num1/num2
    k=k+1
    
print(computed_pi)
```

Output:

```
3.1415926541725754
```